# use the session in the form

Tags: php, forms, session

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['id']='face';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="check.php" method="post">
            Admin:    <input type="text" name="uname" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && !empty($_SESSION['id'])) { echo $_SESSION['id']; }  ?>" /><br />
            Password: <input type="password" name="pword" /><br />
                      <input type="hidden" name="login" value="1" />
                      <input type="submit" value="Login" />
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am working in a php language . i have made session[id] in which i have stored the the value ie face . Now in the form , ADMIN textbox , i am checking for the session[id] , if **isset** or not **empty** **echo**   session[id] but if not **isset** or **empty** echo the textbox value instead of this its showing me tha number . please can any one explain me why its showing me the number .......instead of value

Comment: Your code works fine for me. It puts "face" into the textbox.

Comment: but if the session is not declared  then it will show u the number , try without the session

Comment: It shows empty. What browser are you using? Perhaps Chrome compensates for the answer given by @Benedikt Kittinger

Comment: I am using chrome only but my session is not clicked or and its empty ........then why its showing me the session[id] value in the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `<input type="textbox"` in html!

Use `<input type="text"` or `<textarea> </textarea>` (content goes in between)

**EDIT: Session ID**

If you really want to overwrite the Session ID, use the function session_id(sid). Either way, you can only set the session ID **before** you start the session, so your code should look like this:

```
session_id("face");
session_start();
```

Comment: i have edited that part and thanks .......but it still showing me the session[id] value ..... if i comment out the **$_SESSION['id']='face'** , then also it showing me the session id value

Answer (score 2):

First, correct your html as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="uname" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && !empty($_SESSION['id'])) { echo $_SESSION['id']; }  ?>" />
```

if you get the same error you need to check your session value before displaying the form. You can use:

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

to make sure if your session is not overwritten somewhere else.

Comment: if i comment out the **$_SESSION['id']='face'** , then also it showing me the session id value ..........

Comment: can you leave an screenshot from your page here? I tested your code and it is working fine for me. May be your issue is something else.